# Can I get to Idjwi island from Rwanda?

Tags: ferries, democratic-republic-congo, rwanda

[Idjwi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idjwi) is an island located in the middle of Lake Kivu, between Democratic Republic of Congo and Rwanda, belonging to DRC.

The [Idjwi Island official guide](http://www.idjwiisland.com/getting-there/) mentions

> Recommended Ferrys run from either Goma / Bukavu.

Both of those cities are located in DRC.

Is there any way to visit it directly from the Rwandan side? Or do I have to pass the border in Goma / Bukavu and catch a ferry there?

Comment: It's hard to tell whether that site is actually official; it may be a tour company. Google the phone number and a dozen sites come up, all for package tours/treks. Each one has a disclaimer .. not affiliated with [ICCN](http://www.iccnrdc.org/). The [Bradt Congo guide 2008](https://books.google.com/books?id=cXJyOKBqJZwC&pg=PA208&lpg=PA208&dq=iccn+idjwi+island&source=bl&ots=4FHTvP77vD&sig=e5f8RYr9snAO-RpAL4XV1gNCAlQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwje24yY0eLcAhVJEawKHR2uDl4Q6AEwDHoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=iccn%20idjwi%20island&f=false) says a Rwanda crossing is/was around Kibuye.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that is the only way.

From [another website:](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/africa/democratic-republic-of-congo/visiting-idjwi-island-lake-kivu-from-goma-or-bukavu)

> Visiting Idjwi Island is super-easy from either Goma or Bukavu-- and is highly highly recommended, for a peaceful, friendly and very scenic island.

Additional information:

> Boats from either Goma or Bukavu are plentiful-- either take the MV Mugote, or
>   MV Emmanuel (not Emmanuel 2), or MV Iko (though this one really looks like it's
>   on its last legs). There are plenty of other boats going between Goma and
>   Bukavu but they don't stop on Idjwi. Fares are about $15 for first-class from
>   either Goma or Bukavu, and takes 3-4 hours from Goma and 2-3 hours from Bukavu.

Since 2 fairly official websites give that information I would trust it.

Comment: @kuba did my answer help?